# Get text in containing DIV of clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS:

```
  $(document).on("click", '.like', function (e) {

      $(this).parent().html("<a href = '#' class = 'unlike'><div class = 'heart'></div></a>");
      return false;
  });

  $(document).on("click", '.unlike', function (e) {

      $(this).parent().html("<a href = '#' class = 'like'><div class = 'coal'></div></a>");
      return false;
  });
```

I also have the below html:

```
                  <div>
                   45
                    <a href = "#" class = 'unlike'>

                        <div class = "heart"></div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
```

I am trying to get the integer 45 returned to the console using JS but am unable to do so.  The 45 is in the div. I am trying to get it returned on click using parent/child or next in relation to the existing html.Any advice on how to do this?

I tried doing

```
    id = $(this).parent().text;
    console.log(id);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: The 45 is in the div.  I am trying to get it returned on click using parent/child or next in relation to the existing html.

Comment: What does that have to do with the console? Please say that in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: @sharataka so your question is really "how to I the text of an HTML element"?

Comment: @sharataka You're talking about the JavaScript console, right? Maybe obvious, but just want to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text` is a method, not a property, you have to call it as a function.

```
var value = $(this).parent().text();
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 3):

if you're using chrome dev tools or firebug:

`console.log(value);`

In internet explorer you will need to start the Dev Tools and refresh the page or `console.log` won't work.

to return a value in the `<div>` without an id tag on the div:

```
$(document).on("click", '.like', function (e) {

  $(e.target).parent().html("<a href = '#' class = 'unlike'><div class = 'heart'></div></a>");
  console.log($(e.target).text());
  return false;
});
```

Comment: The 45 is in the div. I am trying to get it returned on click using parent/child or next in relation to the existing html.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var value = $(this).parent().text();
alert($(this).parent().text()); //Alert 45
console.log(value);//print 45 in Console
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
console.log( $(this).parent().text().trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach with single event handler using `toggleClass` method:

```
$(document).on("click", '.like, .unlike', function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('like unlike');
    alert(this.previousSibling.nodeValue);
    return false;
});
```

And we can use plain old javascript to get previous text node value as `this.previousSibling.nodeValue`.

#### Demo http://jsfiddle.net/Q69Bb/